# TypeORM, set default select attributes for an entity

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have an entity with an attribute `isCanceled`. I want the records with `isCanceled` = `true` to be ignored unless I specifically query them.

example:

```
@Entity()
export class Request {
  ...other props

  @Column()
  isCanceled: boolean;
}
```

I thought about extending the `find` and `findOne` methods, but I am not sure if it will take effect in relations, like here.

```
const user = User.findOne({ where: { id: 1 }, relations: { requests: true } })
```